# Why does score:0 search for posts with zero score?

Tags: support, search

If you [s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A1)[e](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-1)[a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-2)[r](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A2)[c](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-3)[h](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A3) for `score:n` where n!=0, it searches for posts with score>=n, but if you [enter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A0) `score:0` it searches for posts with zero score (only score=0). Bug?

Comment: Bug..?  Feature!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. That's how it worked in the beginning, and that's what the syntax became. Eventually they added the range operators (`..`) so you could search for exactly a certain number, but it doesn't make sense to go back and change a syntax that users have already gotten used to.
2. The syntax doesn't *only* affect the score search operator. It also affects the answer search operator. By searching for 0 you're actually searching for "none" - which is more relevant to the answers operator than the votes one. Searching for `answers:0` will search for posts with no answers, which is *extremely* useful in many searches where a "0+" syntax would simply return all questions on the site and be effectively useless.

   The problem here is you don't want to have a syntax for one operator and a different syntax for another operator. Hence, the votes operator inherits the "only zero score" functionality from its answers operator relative.

   (Note the views operators does *not* follow this logic because it's not possible to have 0 views.)

Answer (score 1):

No, because that makes sense to me. If you want score >= 0, use `score:0..`.

Comment: But why score:1 (or -1 or 2) searches for posts with score of 1+ (or -1+ or 2+) score, while score:0 searches for the post of 0 score?

Comment: @nicael Because it makes some sense. If I want to find posts to vote on that are currently neutral, that's what I'd use. I don't have that need for posts score >= 1

Comment: But it works the same way for -ive scores, which makes no sense.  If I'm searching for downvoted posts, I don't also want upvoted ones, which is how it works now.  score=0 matches exactly 0, score=-10 matches -10 up to +whatever.